# Semi circle donut chart python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

Is there a way to create a semi circle donut chart using the pptx library in python?
I couldn't really find any information

Thanks

Comment: you can create a semi-circle pie chart, and then use the formatting options in pptx to change its appearance to that of a donut chart.

Comment: @KartikeyaSharma i couldn't find any information regarding semi-circle pie chart either...

Comment: Can't you create one from matplotlib and then save it as png. Later add it to the slides as ```pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(
    "semi_circle_donut.png", left, top, height=Inches(5), width=Inches(5)
)```

Comment: Answered in detail below

Answer (score 0):

I would do something as below. First I would create a semi pie chart in matplotlib and then I would save it. After saving it I would add it to the presentation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches

data = [20, 30, 50]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.pie(data, startangle=90, radius=1, counterclock=False, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.3))

plt.savefig("semi_circle_donut.png")

prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[6])

left = top = Inches(1)
pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(
    "semi_circle_donut.png", left, top, height=Inches(5), width=Inches(5)
)

prs.save("semi_circle_donut.pptx")
```